# Can this be simplified using CSS flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this setup of photos and thumbnails made with regular CSS, and I was wondering: **can it be simplified using flexbox?**

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/n9pM2/10/

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
    <h1>Can this:</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="photos">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnails">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/70/70" />
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/70/70" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one .photos {
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
.one .photos img {
    width: 100%;
}
.one .thumbnails {
    width: 70px;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.one .thumbnails img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Here's an all-intensive guide to [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I think you could possibly use flex box to display one large image and have all the other ones (smaller), sit below it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm well aware of that article.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/polinq/pen/gObLoZx

Please have a look here. Is that what you were looking for?
Happy to provide clarification if something is not clear?

```
.one .wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.one .thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 5px;
}


.two .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.two .thumbnails  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a lot with grid:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 9fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 14px
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 5px lightgray;
}

.thumbs img{
   border: solid 2px #f00
}
```

```html
<h1>Can this:</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" />
  <div class="thumbs">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/70/70" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/70/70" />
  </div>
</div>
```